# Serving python objects in memory for other python programs

Tags: python, server, nlp, spacy

Consider the following code the second line takes about a minute to finish ,and for each program I have the lines below, so how can i rather serve the nlp object rather than loading it each time from various programs?

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')
```

Ideally something like :

```
nlp=loadservedobject(url)
```

the nlp object is large about > 2GB  hence not looking for serialization solutions.
I would prefer serving an in memory nlp object but dont know how to make a server around a python object?

Ideally the server should be multi threaded.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called serialization. The python package for that is called pickle. You can find the documentation here:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html

```
// save.py

// Save a dictionary into a pickle file.
import pickle
favorite_color = { "lion": "yellow", "kitty": "red" }
pickle.dump(favorite_color, open('save.p', 'wb'))

// load.py

// Load the dictionary back from the pickle file.
import pickle
favorite_color = pickle.load(open('save.p', 'rb'))
// favorite_color is now { "lion": "yellow", "kitty": "red" }
```

Comment: No , its a large object >2 GB and internally that operation is doing deserialization only.

Comment: @stackit with MAP_SHARED

Comment: @stackit and of course the multiprocess api which allows you to share objects: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: Update the answer for the same